# Coldfusion Looping

Tags: loops, coldfusion, cfquery

I need to use `cfloop` to insert records.

There's a form a customer fills out. They add an item from a dropdown list, and then enter in a quantity in a text box. Normally, the quantity is only between 1 and 5.

I need to run a loop to insert the records one at a time with a unique Item ID for each with a quantity of 1.

For example, if they add Specific Item 5 with a quantity of 4, I need 4 records inserted into the table  with a qty of 1 each. What I really want more than the answer here is the thought process of how I'd come to that going forward without having to ask.

Answer (score 1):

That's... a weird way of recording things, but alright.

I am going to assume the form field's names are ITEM and QUANTITY. I am also assuming you are using either SQL or MySQL. The code should be nearly identical for either.

Here is what the code on your action page might look like:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#FORM.QUANTITY#" index="i">
<cfquery name="insertOrder" datasource="DSN">
INSERT INTO TABLENAME
(
ITEMCOLUMN,
QTYCOLUMN
)
VALUES
(
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#FORM.ITEM#">,
1
)
</cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

I added a `cfqueryparam` tag to declare data types and help prevent SQL injection. I don't know what your data types are in actuality, but you should definitely look into using it for any query that takes stuff from the FORM or URL scope.

Comment: So why don't you use `<cfqueryparam>` in your example? You should also validate the input `FORM.QUANTITY` as this will thrown an exception if its content is not a castable numeric. I'm tempted to downvote.

Comment: When you're right, you're right. I didn't want to assume too much about data types and whatever, but half my answer is an assumption anyway. Might as well add a proper example.

Comment: Thanks @TRose .. your assumptions are correct and yea, I always SQL injection. If that's a weird way of doing it, any suggestions? :)

Comment: @kevinfreese my only question is why can you only count the quantity one at a time? You could bypass the need for a loop.

Comment: @TRose These are my instructions: 
If they Add a new piece of equipment do the following after they submit the form:
1 - Check to see if the item selected is serialized (by a query)
2 - Split logic based on if find item is serialized or not
  a. Serialized - Will create a loop to insert one record at a time with a quantity of 1 that will loop for the quantity specified on the form, but only save any serial number on 1st record
  b - Non-serialized - Will create one record with the quantity specified on the form - if enter a serial number for some reason, go ahead and save it

Answer (score 1):

Which flavor of SQL are you using? Rather than make a db connection and inserting once for each item, you may be able to do something like this:

```
<<<< sanitize FORM inputs >>>>

<cfquery name="insertRecords" datasource="#APPLICATION.DSN#">
    INSERT INTO <TheTable> ( ItemID, Qty, <OtherDetails> )
    VALUES 
        <cfloop from="1" to="#sanitizedFORMQuantity# index="i">
            ( 
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#sanitizedItemID#">
                , 1
                , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#sanitizedOtherDetails#"> 
            )  
            <cfif index NEQ sanitizedFORMQuantity>,</cfif> 
        </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

This lets you build up the query and perform a single INSERT, making just one connection to the database. Even with just 5 items, it will be much faster.

NOTES:

1. ALWAYS sanitize FORM inputs (and any other data coming from any
   source other than you). queryparam primarily handles SQLi, but may
   allow other exploits to pass through.
2. Check that your cfsqltypes appropriately match up with the
   datatypes of the columns in your database. Know which ones work
   together to prevent unneeded background data conversions.
   https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html
3. Try to minimize the number of times you need to connect to the
   database. Especially if your application and database reside on
   different servers (which they should).

Answer (score 0):

Really minor changes to Shawn's excellent answer

```
<cfquery name="insertRecords" datasource="#APPLICATION.DSN#">
DECLARE @OtherDetails varchar(80) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#sanitizedOtherDetails#"> 

INSERT INTO <TheTable> ( ItemID, Qty, <OtherDetails> )
VALUES 
    <cfloop from="1" to="#sanitizedFORMQuantity# index="i">
        ( 
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_smallint" value="#sanitizedItemID#">
            , 1
            , @otherDetails
        )  
        <cfif index NEQ sanitizedFORMQuantity>,</cfif> 
    </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

1. This will create fewer temp variables
2. If you are really creating more than a small int number of variables, you have a real problem in the approach.